# Using Xmonad with custom keys to launch a function?

Tags: xmonad

How do I do this? I tried the following method but it gives me an error saying my brackets are mismatched etc. I am not even sure if the function entry is correct

```
main = xmonad defaultConfig
    { terminal    = "terminator"
    , modMask     = mod4Mask
    , borderWidth = 3
    , layoutHook = myLayout
    , keys = inskeys
    }

inskeys :: XConfig l -> [((KeyMask, KeySym), X ())]
inskeys conf@(XConfig {modMask = modm}) =
[ ((mod1Mask,             xK_F2  ), saveCurrentWorkspace) ]

getLayout :: X (Layout Window)
getLayout = gets $ W.layout . W.workspace . W.current . windowset




myLayout = tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| Full
  where
    tiled = spacing 5 $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
    nmaster = 1
    ratio = 1/2
    delta = 3/100

saveCurrentWorkspace :: X ()
saveCurrentWorkspace = do 
                        Layout x <- getLayout
                        liftIO $ writeFile "currentLayout" (show x)
```

Answer (score 0):

To map custom keys to launch a function do the following.
Add this to your xmonad.hs

```
myAdditionalKeys = [
  ((mod1Mask .|. xK_F12), saveCurrentWorkspace),
]
```

And add

```
`addtionialKeys myAddtionialKeys`
```

at the end of your "main" function, like in the following example.

```
main = do
  xmonad $ defaultConfig
         { manageHook = manageSpawn <+> myManageHook <+> manageDocks,
           layoutHook = myLayout,
           logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP {
                   ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc,
                   ppLayout = (\ x -> ""),
                   ppTitle = xmobarColor "#b2ed00" ""
                 } >> updatePointer (Relative 0.99 0.99),
           modMask = mod4Mask,
           borderWidth = 4,
           normalBorderColor = "#777777",
           focusedBorderColor = "#ccff00",
           workspaces = myWorkspaces,
           focusFollowsMouse = True,
           terminal = "x-terminal-emulator"
         }
         `removeKeys` myRemoveKeys
         `additionalKeys` myAdditionalKeys
```